# How to select what files should be deployed when deploying an app to GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using python for my GAE development. How can I select what files I want to be uploaded when deploying an app to GAE? (Or equivalently if I could select what files to ignore, that would also work) By default, I assume the deployer uploads all the files it can find in the directory that is to be deployed.

Comment: use push-to-deploy and .gitignore or only add to git what is needed

Comment: I am not using push-to-deploy. I just want to be able to tell the deployer, these are the files I want you to upload and please ignore the rest or vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use skip_files in your app.yaml
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files

> The skip_files element specifies which files in the application
>   directory are not to be uploaded to App Engine. The value is either a
>   regular expression, or a list of regular expressions. Any filename
>   that matches any of the regular expression is omitted from the list of
>   files to upload when the application is uploaded.